# Why transition does not work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate the yellow square when you mouse over it. I think I have tried nearly everything but it does not want to move. However, if I apply same transition and transform to the input field it starts to rotate. What is the problem here? Thanx for your help.

```css
#sqre {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: gold;
border: 2px solid black;
transition: 1s;
}

#sqre:hover {
transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="numb" />
<div id="sqre">square</div>
```

Comment: [Working fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5fsy2L0b/). What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Safari on mobile

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce issue. Your example works perfectly fine: http://scratchpad.io/lewd-growth-7706

Comment: You need to use `-webkit-` for safari

Comment: Hm. Sorry, can't test that. But have you tried appending a `-webkit-` prefix to the `transition` property? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) seems to indicate it's still necessary.

Comment: I don't fine any issues here. Its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/sinthu225/otjakaL3/

Comment: It does not work with a -webkit- prefix either. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @CeeJay just posted answer to your query for mobile resolutions. Please check if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hovers aren't possible on mobile devices as there is no persistent cursor - memory of the last touched point by default.

The only way they can sense interaction is touch, which is akin to a click or selection, so onclick in Javascript are other suitable opions for mobile.

```js
$('#sqre').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle');
  $('#sqre').not(this).removeClass('toggle');
});
```

```css
#sqre {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: 1s;
}

#sqre.toggle {
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" name="numb" />
<div id="sqre">square</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here I change `rotateZ` to `-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)` and it works perfectly
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cggmrvze/)

Comment: Note that you shouldn't just change `transform` to `-webkit-transform`, you should leave the current property as is and add a new -webnkit- property, in order to keep the compatibility with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you have used in the question is working just fine.
You can see it in action below :

```css
#sqre {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: 1s;
}

#sqre:hover {
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="numb" />
<div id="sqre">square</div>
```

Also, if you are trying to achieve anything else, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with the code I posted and it doesn't work with a -webkit- prefix either. It is really strange, cause input field transition works perfectly fine. Could it be safari mobile issue?